# Angular 2 Routing- Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a simple angular application in which I had created a login component.

After Successful login user need to land on dashboard page, I had created a dashboard component for same as well.

Then I had tried to use Angular Navigation created a route file

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './dash-board/dash-board.component';

export const rotuer: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashBoard', component: DashBoardComponent },
 { path: 'App', component: AppComponent },
// { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
 ];
 export const routes: ModuleWithProviders  =RouterModule.forRoot(rotuer);
```

Reference of code file had taken on app Module

```
import {routes} from './app.route'

imports: [
   BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 routes,
// RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)

],
```

Now I have a Log in button on login component, on click of that I am invoking a function

```
 login() {
     alert(this.user.email);
      alert(this.user.password);
    // this.router.navigate(['/hero']);
      this.router.navigate(['App']);
   }
```

I am able to receive user email and Password but  this.router.navigate(['App']); or  this.router.navigate(['DashBoard is throwing error']);

Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashBoardComponent'

I had tried to placed 

on
1. Login
2. Dasboard.
3 On Both page

but still n
ot able to resolve.

Comment: please show your html code also

Comment: u have to paste <router-outlet></router-outlet> on your base component's template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have missed `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` which acts as a placeholder and replaced by template which navigate route points to.

Put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the page from where you try to navigate to the dashboard page. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to have a paste a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the component template on which you have to load the components.

My git hub repo post - https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html